# Hypothetically: Add Blazor Mobile Blazor Bindings to existing Blazor WASM project

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm about to choose framework for a future project.
As of now I'm leaning to choose Blazor WASM since it looks really promising.

But in the future my customer would like to have push notifications (since it's not currently available through PWA on iOS) and maybe some other platform specific sensor that's only reachable through a native app (or Xamarin...).
In the future, if Mobile Blazor Bindings becomes a LTS, do you see any showstoppers to add a Mobile Blazor Bindings project to a existing Blazor project. If we create our components in a separate component library, independently from the target framework, would this be possible?

I understand that this is hypothetically but what are your thoughts? :)
Thanks in advance and hope you'll have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

The mobile blazor bindings target native apps  so you can't add them to an existing blazor web project.

If you keep your components and logic in separate projects you will be able to reuse them on your new mobile app.

Note, however, that the mobile blazor bindings target native components while you will now be writing web components, so in your future mobile app you will either need new mobile components or you will be stuck in a web view, which might not be optimal. Also, assets for a web view mobile app are vastly different from a real web app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
I was maybe a bit unclear in my post.
Yeah I know that MBB are native, but if I create most of my logic and components in 
a seperate Razor component library project could i refer/use them in my MBB app? In that way the re-useability would be great.

Comment: Logic - yes. Components - not so much - theoretically, you should be able to reuse them in a web view, but NOT as native components

Comment: Yes @rdmptn, as you say I will have to use them as a web view in that case.